# Entity Framework Modeling User Friendships

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, social-networking

I'm trying to create a Friend relationship for my User table for my site. I'm using MVC3 and EF4.1. Here is what I have so far (non-working). Any advice and suggestions is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

```
public class User{
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<User> Buddies {get;set;}
}
/* mapping table for user to user friendships */
public class Friendship{
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    public int BuddyID {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my basic understanding of this, I believe your approach is good.

Anyway, I would treat this as a generic databases problem rather than EntityFramework-specific; there should be tons of material in the web. For example, this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560065/using-php-and-mysql-how-to-structure-a-friendship-in-database-for-a-community) might have some useful things for you.

Hope this helps!